# Sum based on drop-down list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have this table and I would like to sum the amount from the drop down list.

Lets say I have few categories from my drop down menu (column L) and on column P I would like to have the amount I inserted in column I.

For example, every time I pick Plant Cost from drop down list in Column L, the amount in P7 will auto sum the amount, in my attached picture I supposed to have 4,717.00. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that the text values in column O exactly match your drop down values, you could put this into `P7` and copy it down to the cells below:

`=SUMIF($L$2:$L$1000,O7,$I$2:$I$1000)`

If your table has more than 1000 rows, then increase the `1000` on the end of the ranges in the formula, or format as a table and reference the entire column instead.

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful.